# Off screen display with textinput and scrollview in react-native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput

I am creating an app in react-native and I'm having problem with the display. 
I have a textinput in scrollview. When I tap on the textinput and it's focused, the display will go up and goes off screen.

I have seen the same issue posted in github.

Here is the link: [Github issue posted by someone](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7132)

Comment: Are you using react native on Android or iOS? Is it going off screen to the height of the keyboard?

Comment: I am using it on Android. Yes, goes off screen when the keyboard was shown and I thinks the height of the off screen part matches the height that was added in the bottom when I scroll it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of they keyboard for Android. You have to manually change the `android:windowSoftInputMode` in AndroidManifest.xm to another option (`adjustNothing` is more iOS like). See the options here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft.

Also, keep in mind that `keyboardWillShow()` and `keyboardWillHide()` are not fired on Android, **and** if you opt to use `adjustNothing`, not even `keyboardDidShow()` or `keyboardDidHide()` are fired.

I would recommend keeping the default behavior of `android:windowSoftInputMode`, but use the `keyboardDidShow()` and `keyboardDidHide()` to manually adjust the ScrollView position.

Comment: I already did that. I adjust the height with keyboardDidShow() and keyboardDidHide() but it still goes off the screen and there's a space between the textinput and keyboard.

Comment: At this point without seeing code it could be anything from margin in the styles or something too.

Comment: It's something with margin of the textinput? the code is something like this: `<ToolbarAndroid /> <ChatThread /> <TypingArea />` and the textinput is located in the TypingArea